# Django rest framework - how to serialise the model class name base serialiser?

Tags: python, json, django, inheritance, django-rest-framework

I have a **BaseModel** class:

```
class BaseModel(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=250, blank=True, null=True)
    class Meta:
        abstract = True
```

Then I have mutliple model classes that extend such class e.g.:

```
class Article(BaseModel):
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=250, default=timezone.now, unique=True)
```

My goal is to have a field in a JSON object returned through my webservices to  indicate the type of the object (so that the client applications can easily tell an Article from a e-commerce Product). Something like the following:

```
{
   "id": 1,
   "object_type: "article",
   "title": "some article",
   "slug": "some-article"
}
```

I imagine the there could be a **BaseModelSerializer** class similar to the following:

```
class BaseModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    object_type = self.__class__.__name__ # ??? how to get the name/ label of the child class?
```

Then I can have a **ArticleSerializer** extending the **BaseModelSerializer** like the following:

```
class ArticleSerializer(BaseModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Article
```

I would be happy if this could be achieved through modifying the **BaseModel** class too. Something like the following?

```
class BaseModel(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=250, blank=True, null=True)
    object_type = self.__class__.__name__ # ??? how to get the name/ label of the child class?
    class Meta:
        abstract = True
```

Comment: Look at `@property` decorator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [SerializerMethodField](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#serializermethodfield).

```
class BaseModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    object_type = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    def get_object_type(obj):
        return obj.__class__.__name__.lower()


class ArticleSerializer(BaseModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Article
        fields = ('object_type',)
```

Comment: Just in case, adding decorator `@staticmethod` above `def get_object_type(obj):` is helped me to avoid error `get_object_type() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given`.